# Convert data type of property for all objects in an array

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Say I have an array of objects:

```
$a = @(
    @{ Name = "A"; Value = "2016-01-02" },
    @{ Name = "B"; Value = "2016-01-03" },
    @{ Name = "C"; Value = "2016-01-04" }
)
```

The `Value` property is currently a `String`. I want to convert the `Value` property of each object to a `DateTime`. I could accomplish this with a `for` loop, but I was wondering if there is a more direct way to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, calculated properties.

```
$a | select @{N='Name';E={$_.Name}}, @{N='Value';E={ [datetime]$_.Value }}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I've used something quite similar in `Sort-Object -Property ...` expressions to sort by some expression instead of a property on the object.

Comment: I've seen other examples (after seeing this answer) that use "Name" instead of "N" and "Expression" instead of "E". I tested and both work. However, other abbreviations (e.g. "Nm" and "Exp") do not work--I'll stick with "N" and "E" for the brevity.

Comment: @neizan you can use the shortest unambiguous version (this also applies to parameters to functions/cmdlets), so `Exp` is fine, `Nm` is not, `N`, `Na`, `Nam` would all work.

Comment: @briantist Ah! Did not know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will change data type of the  first object Value to datetime.

```
$a[0].value = [datetime]::ParseExact($a[0].value,'yyyy-MM-dd',$null)
```

And the loop from here :

```
foreach ($Obj in $a)
    {
    $Obj.Value = [datetime]::ParseExact($Obj.value,'yyyy-MM-dd',$null)
    }
```

The @TessellatingHeckler 's answer, which you accepted, is not correct for your question! It is only change the representation of the data in the object, but not converted it as you ask. Even if you save it as a new object (or overwrite the original) this will change the object itself. You can see the difference if you run flowing code:

```
$b=$a | select @{N='Name';E={$_.Name}}, @{N='Value';E={ [datetime]$_.Value }}
#check the original and converted object
$a|gm
$b|gm
```